# Creating a dictionary from a file with filenames and keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I only get the date in the list now instead of the location, date, and caption in the list when I test this. Can anyone please help me fix this? The end result is supposed to look like this.

```
{filename: [location, date, caption]}
```

Here is the file.

```
images/skating.jpg,East York Arena,2014.11.03,Shea skating.,skating,Shea,boy
images/sunglasses.jpg,High Park,2013.02.03,Cool guy.,Shea,sunglasses,happy
images/skating2.jpg,East York Arena,2014.11.03,Shea skating 
again!,skating,Shea

def create_image_dict(open_csv_file):
'''(file) -> dict of {str: list of str}

The open csv file has the format:
filename,location,date,caption,keywords,keywords, ...
Return a dictionary with key filename and values [location, date, caption]
'''
d = {}
for line in open_csv_file:
    info = line.split(',')
    filename = info[0]
    location = info[1]
    date = info[2]
    caption = info[3]
    if location not in d:
        d[filename] = {location:{date: caption}}
return d
```

Comment: debug your `line`,then you will find the problem.

Comment: `import csv` is more robust.

Comment: I already tried that. The error is still there

Answer (score 1):

Pro Tip 1:

> Do debug print statements to see what is being worked on i.e. print(info)

The problem is most likely due to the split leaving a list with a single entry.

```
arr = "this string will not split to more than one element".split(",")
```

The `arr` will now be length 1 and hence will throw error for `arr[1]`

**Edit**

Looking at your program again you seem to be checking the wrong thing for insert into dict `d`. You should be checking `if filename in d` rather than `if location in d`.

Comment: Ok, but what about for the other ones?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean for the indexes besides 1

Comment: In Python when you get an error, unless you handle it, then the rest of the code will not run i.e. will not attempt to access the other elements as you have done.

You can test this theory and swap `caption = info[3]` with `location = info[1]` and you will get the same error but with the former instead of the latter.

Comment: If you use `try/except` or if you put a guard in place to say only go through and access elements after `if len(info) >= 4` or something.

Comment: But it only goes up to 3 in this case.

Comment: but Python is a `0-index` language so it is `[0,1,2,3]` which is `4` items.

Comment: Oh ok, so I could just add the if statement after the split line?

Comment: yes. Then you can sleep safely that you have at least enough elements to index.

Comment: Is there a general way to do it? without hard coding?

Comment: do you have headers? if so use pandas or csv module.

Comment: I'm using a csv file to test this and there are no headers.

Comment: then use `try` and `except` where you put all your code within a `try` then add a `except` block - same style/indentation as an `if` and `else`.

Comment: I got it to test properly now, but I get this when I test it. {'images/skating.jpg': {'East York Arena': ['2014.11.03']}, 'images/sunglasses.jpg': {'High Park': ['2013.02.03']}, 'images/skating2.jpg': {'East York Arena': ['2014.11.03']}}. How come the date is only in a list and why is the location not in the list and why is the caption not even there?